# Binary Converter For Loop Trouble

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, binary, converters

So I am making a binary converter for science project and I am having a bit of difficulty.

As of now, I am trying to write a for loop that gets each individual variable of the user's input into a seperate variable.

However, I can't find a way to only create the same number of variables as the length of the string provided, so I can only use document.write, which is not what I want.

Can anyone help me figure out how to store each character of a string into a seperate variable and post that solution here please?

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: What do you mean by _each individual variable of the user's input_?

Comment: And what is a binary converter?

Comment: "post that solution here" -- we're not a code factory. We are here to help.

Comment: "how to store each character of a string into a seperate variable" -- ever heard of arrays? Moreover did you know you can index into a string, like `"abc"[1] === "b"`?

Comment: `store each character of a string into a separate variable` Did you try `("Foobar")[2];`? A string is some kind of an `Array`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys I figured out what to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are array-like objects.  They expose a `length` property and support array indexers to access the individual characters of the string.  You can simply use a `for` loop to iterate through the characters.

```
var myString = "Hello World";
for(var i=0; i<myString.length; i++) {
    var character = myString[i];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Technically, strings are pseudo-arrays. They don't have all the fancy methods that real arrays have.

Comment: If you want it to be treated like a normal array, use `.call` like this: `[].forEach.call("foobar",function(el){ console.log(el) });` (replace `forEach` with the method you need)

Comment: @JanDvorak Yessir!  I have updated my answer, although I don't think it mattered to the OP :)

Comment: @Derek I prefer `Array.prototype.` even if it's longer.

Comment: @JanDvorak Sure that `Array.prototype` is easier to understand.

Comment: I suggest "strings are arrays (technically, pseudo-arrays) of characters"

Comment: @Derek I don't always stick to what is easier to understand :-) `if(~[10,12].indexOf(x))` `while(x-->0)` `~~3.14`

Comment: @JanDvorak - Woah woah woah what in the world is that? `~[10,12]`

Comment: @Derek you got the priorities wrong. `indexOf` returns `-1` if it doesn't find anything, which I promply bitwise-negate to `0`, which is falsy. Bitwise-negating an array would not be too useful.

Comment: @JanDvorak - o.O It appears to be less confusing than `a = [b][b = a,0];`

Comment: @Derek what does it do? It seems to swap `a` and `b` but then I prefer `[a,b]=[b,a]` that comes in Javascript 1.7 or the plain old temp.

Comment: @JanDvorak - It is a fast way to swap `a` and `b` ;) And by the way, `Invalid left-hand side in assignment` when I try `[a,b]=[b,a]` :(

Comment: @Derek Chrome doesn't support this syntax yet :-( . Try this in Firefox.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Wow that's cool, but the syntax is kind of confusing (or is it that I'm not used to this syntax?)

Comment: @Derek your comma swap seems to perform poorly in all browsers, and the temp-swap is the fastest everywhere. Chrome performs temp-swap, xor-swap and +/- swap equally well, while in other browsers it's temp-swap > xor-swap > +/- swap > comma swap : http://jsperf.com/integer-swap

Comment: @JanDvorak - Well by "fast" I mean fewer keys for me to type.

Comment: @Derek Keystroke-wise, the destructured assignment is the clear winner (even beats the comma-swap). Sadly I cannot test its performance or use it IRL. It's not confusing at all. It's just parallel assignment to all elements of a literal array of lvalues.

Comment: So I probably have to put an if statement and process each letter as it goes through the loop?